# ¿Porque cuando quiero borrar el valor de una variable en c# me marca error?

Tags: c#, variables

El problema es que cada vez que ingrese a un if que eh creado me debe de borrar la variable flotante donde almaceno información, solo que esa información es de cada 3 meses y yo me to información de cada 12 meses, lo que requiero es que cuando entre al if significa que es un trimestre, por lo cual me debe de hacer el calculo trimestral y antes de salir borrar la variable para que cuando vuelva a ingresar no contenga información de meses anteriores.

Todo bien hasta ahí, porque si me hace ese procedimiento durante como unas 6 o 7 iteraciones, pero después quiebra y me dice error.

```
    private string[] naciones;
    private float[] media;
    private float[,] mediaT;
    private float[,] mensual;
    private string linea;
    private int cantidad;
    private float mediaM=0.0f;
    private float mediaTr = 0.0f;
    private int z = 0;

public void cargar()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de paises");
    linea = Console.ReadLine();
    cantidad = int.Parse(linea);
    naciones=new string[cantidad];
    mensual=new float[cantidad,12];
    media=new float[cantidad];
    mediaT = new float[cantidad,4];

    for (int x = 0; x < naciones.Length;x++ )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del pais");
        naciones[x] = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int y = 0; y < mensual.GetLength(1);y++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese La temperatura");
            linea = Console.ReadLine();
            mensual[x, y] = float.Parse(linea);
            mediaM=mediaM+float.Parse(linea);
            mediaTr = mediaTr + float.Parse(linea);

            if (y==2 || y==5 || y==8 || y==11) {
                Console.WriteLine("ENTRO");
                z = z + 1;
                    mediaTr = mediaTr / 3;
                    mediaT[x, z] = mediaTr;
                    mediaTr = 0.0f; ----> ERROR


            }

        }
        media[x] = mediaM / 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías indicar el error ?

Comment: el error esta indicado con una flecha que dice error en el codigo

Comment: Me refiero que está arrojando el programa, una excepción ?  No te deja asignar ese valor en tiempo de edición? Si la tienes podrías editar tu pregunta indicando el contenido o el mensaje de esa excepción?

Comment: Como sugerencia, ya que probé tu código es que chequees bien que las matrices no se pasen de sus dimensiones,  no veo como pueda darte error la variable `mediaTr`, la que me sugiere que puede salirse de límites es `mediaT`

Comment: oh ya gracias, y la excepción me la da el asistente de visual studio, me dice que si deseo interrumpir la acción, pero no me da un error especifico, gracias por la sugerencia, veré si eso arregla mi situacion

Comment: ahora entiendo , lo que quieres guardar en `mediaT` es la media trimestral  por cada país que tengas, es así?

Comment: si exactamente, eso es lo que quiero realizar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error lo tienes en esta porción de código al cargar el 4 trimestre:

```
z = z + 1
```

Ten en cuenta que los arreglos (*arrays*) en C# son Base Cero, por ejemplo tu arreglo `mediaT` lo inicializas como `mediaT = new float[cantidad,4]` pero empiezas a llenar tu arreglo `mediaT` desde la posición 1 y al llegar al 4to trimestre `z` vale 5.

La solución sería incrementar la variable después de la asignación, es decir hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 mediaTr = mediaTr / 3;
 mediaT[x, z] = mediaTr;
 mediaTr = 0.0f;
 z = z + 1;
```

Espero haber sido claro, cualquier cosa no dudes en comentar!